# Can [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:int] be used multiple times in an application

Tags: iphone

Can I use this API multiple times using the lifetime. When I try to do that, this does not update the application badge.

Anything I might be missing.

Regards
Nitin

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it can be used however many times you want.

It might help to show the code you're using to set it, see if there's anything wrong there.

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationBadgeString:@"x"];

Comment: It's setApplicationBadgeNumber: and it has to be an integer.